# Simple cron with flock not working on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I've created the file `crontester` on `/etc/cron.d` with this line on it:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/fcj.lockfile touch /tmp/test.txt
```

That should be running every minute.

But I dont see the `/tmp/test.txt` file being created, so the cron is not working correctly.

What I'm doing wrong? Do I've to create the `/tmp/fcj.lockfile`, if I've to do this, do I have to create it empty?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The command runs fine on my machine, so the cronjob is probably not set up properly. `man cron` discourages creating `/etc/cron.d/` files:

> Like /etc/crontab, the files in the /etc/cron.d directory are monitored for changes. In  general,  the  system  administrator should not use /etc/cron.d/, but use the standard system crontab /etc/crontab.

Try creating the cronjob using `crontab -e` and see if it works